# Javascript show/hide, show first div on page load

Tags: javascript

Can you help me to make the first div show on page load?

```js
function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.tabContent {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#contenuto"><div tabindex="1" class="tabs"><div id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff(this)">CARATTERISTICHE</div><div class="triangle-down-tab"></div></div></a>

<a href="#contenuto" ><div tabindex="2" class="tabs"><div id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff(this)">DESTINATARI</div><div class="triangle-down-tab"></div></div></a>

<a href="#contenuto"><div tabindex="3" class="tabs"><div id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff(this)"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#000000;"></i> CALENDARIO</div><div class="triangle-down-tab"></div></div></a>

<a name="contenuto"><hr></a>

<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent">
    <p>tab 1</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent">
    <p>tab 2 tab 2 </p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3" class="tabContent">
    <p>tab 3 tab 3 tab 3</p>
</div>
```

This is my actual code. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Revy94/rb5c5095/)
Thanks!

Comment: `div` with `tabs-1` id ?

Comment: Yes, i want to show the tabs-1 div on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sure can. When you do this kind of stuff best use css. That way when the dom loads the css will kick in and your desired effect will show.

Further more its easier to understand and easier to code up.

```
.tabContent  {
    display:none;
}
.tabContent.active  {
    display:block;
}
```

Then in the HTML

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent active">
```

So when the page loads tab one is active

Then in your JS

```
function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 

      tabContents[i].className="tabContent";
    }

    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).className="tabContent active";
}
```

Updated fiddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/rb5c5095/3/

We could improve things since we know all the tabs will be made invisible at boot up and tab 1 will show. So when a tab is clicked we could just search the tab who has .active class and remove it, then apply the .active class to the new tab. This would have the benefit that any extra css you add in your html markup would not be removed by the JS code, but i reckon you can work that out and if you can't get back to me i can show you :-)

Comment: Thanks! How can i make the link to the first tab focus on page load?

Comment: When you say focus what do you mean - the first tab shows the first tab content on focus do you mean you want that tab to be lit up?

Comment: If you want to make it light up show that it is focused. Then you would add a .active class to that tab. In the css add the styling to make it looked focus. Add the .active class to that tab in the html, then in your code remove and add the .active class as we have done for the content.

Comment: Yes, exactly, i want the first tab to be light up

Comment: I tried to use the .active class but the first tab remains lighted up when i click on another one

Comment: Yes because in your onlick event you would need to remove the current active on the tab and add it to the new tab in the same way we deal with content.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rb5c5095/7/ i have updated this fiddle the tabs are now lit yellow when clicked sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a function when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    showTab("tabs-1");

function showTab(divId) {
    //Get the element
    var divElement= document.getElementbyId(divId);
    //Set the css property  "display" from "none" to be "block";
    divElement..style.display = "block";
}
}):
```

The function should run once the page has fully loaded.
Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am invoking the function (upon page load) that tweaks the css of the desired block;
Same can be achieved by $(document).ready;
I took this approach to avoid jquery;

```
window.onload =  showDivOne();

function showDivOne() {
    document.getElementById("tabs-1").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.